# How to remove title from Tabhost?

Tags: android, youtube

I am working with you tube video playlist. In one of my tab I want to fetch image from server and other tab fetch videos from YouTube playlist. Both are working, but I have some problem in tab 2, in that appears a title.

I don't know how to remove that title.

**Screenshot of my emulator is:**

[image]

**cm_yt_list_items.xml :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Image View
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>`

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try : `tabLayout.getTabAt(TABINDEX).setText("");`

Comment: Post your xml please